# zClip not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

http://jsfiddle.net/w4eL7/1/

its not working in my case because my copy handler the `copy id` is hidden initially and zClip has a check for hidden element

```
 if (o.is(':visible') && (typeof settings.copy == 'string' || $.isFunction(settings.copy)))
```

so i removed `o.is(':visible')` check from it but still its not working, my swf file is placed at right place.

on checking i found that

```
clip.addEventListener('mouseDown', function (client) {
                        o.trigger('mousedown');
                        if(!$.isFunction(settings.copy)){
                            clip.setText(settings.copy);
                        } else {
                            clip.setText(o.triggerHandler('zClip_copy'));
                        }                        
                        if ($.isFunction(settings.beforeCopy)) {
                            o.trigger('zClip_beforeCopy');                            
                        }
                    });
```

is not working i mean any thing inside the `addeventlistner` is not working at all, can anybody either tell me the workaround of doing it or can help me in fixing it

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First remove the `display: none;` in `.rightMenu` in the css-file. It will be hidden after the zclip-call which moved to the beginning. I made some more smaller changes (look also at my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wV3H8/).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var selectedElement = null;

    $("#copyChildDivId").zclip({
        path: "swf/ZeroClipboard.swf",
        copy: function() {
            return (selectedElement !== null ? $(selectedElement).attr("id") : "");
        },
        afterCopy: function() {
            $('#rightMenuItem').hide();
        }
    });
    $('.rightMenu').hide();

    $(".item").bind("contextmenu", function(e) {
        $('#rightMenuItem').css({
            top: e.pageY+'px',
            left: e.pageX+'px'
        }).show();
        selectedElement = this;
        return false;
    });

});
```

Comment: seems to be some issue at my end... its working fine on jsfiddle but not working in my application... is there any prerequisite for the same? which i might be missing?

Comment: Only jquery has to be integrated and the swf has to be at the given path (have you tried to use the external path like in my jsfiddle?). To help anymore I need more informations.

Comment: I forgot to mention the jquery zclip plugin. Have you added it (`<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.zclip.min.js"></script>`)?

Comment: obviously yes.. added the normal not the minified 1